# React Form register input value and text

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

here's my form

```
const AddSection = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = formData => {}

    return <form onSubmit={() => { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }}>
        <select {...register("id", { required: true })}>
            {
                options.map(o => (
                    <option key={`o-${o.id}`} value={o.id}>{m.name}</option>
                ))
            }
        </select>
    </form>
}
```

In onSubmit I'm trying to get select value and text

I tried the following. but that's not perfect as for me + it doesn't work properly in all the cases.

```
const AddSection = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();
    register("text")

    ...

    return <form onSubmit={() => { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }}>
        <select 
            {...register("id", { required: true })}
            onChange={event => setValue("text", event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].text)}
        >
           ...
        </select>
    </form>
}
```

Does anyone know the right way to do that ?

Comment: Looks like you did whats possible. In what cases this doesn´t work properly? Also, can you use a 3rd library for `select` or you need to use the pure `select`?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto pure select

Answer (score 1):

This works, it doesn't use the useForm hook but every time a new option is selected, it saves the value and text in the "user" state which is an object with the keys: value and text. Then console.log()s on submit.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const AddSection = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    let options = [
        { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
        { id: 2, name: "Bob Builder" },
    ];

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(user);
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <select
                required
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setUser({
                        value: e.target.value,
                        text: e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text,
                    });
                }}
            >
                {options.map((o) => (
                    <option key={`o-${o.id}`} value={o.id}>
                        {o.name}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    );
};

export default AddSection;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to do it using reacy useForm hook

Answer (score 1):

You did it the right way. Maybe
inside the `onchange` function, you can call another function `onOptionSelect`. The issue will probably be in passing values from the `select` component. So console it here and debug.
You can use react form Controller as below.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="bank"
  rules={{
    required: 'Bank is required',
  }}
  render={({ onChange, name, value }) => (
    <select
    {...register("id", { required: true })}
    onChange={(val: any) => {
      onChange(val);
      onOptionSelect(val);
      }}
    >
  )}
/>

const onOptionSelect = (opt: any) => {
  console.log(opt);
  setValue('userId', opt._id);
  setValue('username', opt.name);
};
```

You can also do it using a new `useState` variable as mentioned in @Benjamin Bialy's answer.

Refer https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Multiselect from "./Multiselect.js";

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const App = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, setValue, control, watch, reset } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
    shouldUnregister: true,
    defaultValues: {
      disciplines: []
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await sleep(50);
      setValue("disciplines", ["bbb", "ccc"], { shouldValidate: true });
      reset({ disciplines: ["bbb", "ccc"] });
    })();
  }, []);

  const values = watch();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(console.log)}>
      <Multiselect
        name={"disciplines"}
        label={"Disciplines"}
        control={control}
        values={["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]}
      />

      <button>submit</button>

      <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 4)}</pre>
    </form>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get select value by:-

```js
const AddSection = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = formData => {alert(JSON.stringify(formData.id));}

    return <form onSubmit={() => { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }}>
        <select {...register("id", { required: true })}>
            {
                options.map(o => (
                    <option key={`o-${o.id}`} value={o.id}>{o.name}</option>
                ))
            }
        </select>
    </form>
}
```

After getting value if you can you can loop through `options` array to get the text also.